# What are the security issues of exposing default server home page in public internet?

Tags: webserver, information-gathering

I have seen on internet where several website companies have exposed the default home page of web server such as Tomcat, NGNIX, Apache web server. I always believe it is not the best practice to  expose default web server page. But now a days most of the web-servers avoid any sensitive information in home page. So at present is there any issue in exposing default web server pages to internet?

Answer (score 1):

Exposure of these details allow attackers to conduct **enumeration**, which is the process to extract and obtain information of targets in order to launch future attacks.  For example, knowing the PHP version that is running on a particular server allows an attacker to find what vulnerabilities are on that particular version that could be exploited, providing that these have not been patched. This is just a simplistic example of enumeration.

There are website resources out there that discuss this in further detail, the techniques used to enumerate various information, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack exchange!

You may not have sensitive information but you will expose platform running behind the web service (You have also identified some of the platforms running - Tomcat, NGNIX, Apache web serve, etc based on your search)

By knowing the platform the hackers/attackers could send targeted attacks using the known vulnerabilities of those platforms (easy reconnaissance for attackers).

Hence It's always recommended to hide the default web page.